# Vue add an search option

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In my current component i need to add an search option, i have the following:

```
<log
    v-for="log in logs"
    :log="log"
    :key="log.id">
</log>

import Log from './partials/Log';

export default {

    components: {
        Log
    },

    data() {
        return {
            logs: []
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.fetchLogs();
    },
    methods: {
        fetchLogs() {
                axios.get('/api/logs/').then((res) => {
                this.logs= res.data.data;      
            });
        }
    }
}
```

In ./partials/Log';

```
<template>
    <div class="media">
         <p>{{ log.name  }}</p>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['log']
    }
</script>
```

How can i add an search to my component, tried to use an computed property but can't make it yet.

Any suggestion or ideas ?

Comment: And search what? I need more info to help you

Comment: I need to search for `<p>{{ log.name  }}</p>` in`./partials/Log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import Log from './partials/Log';

export default {

    components: {
        Log
    },

    data() {
        return {
            logs: [],
            logFilterWord: ""
        }
    },
      computed: {
     filteredlogs: function()
     {
      return this.logs.filter(test => {return test.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.logFilterWord.toLowerCase())})
     }
  }
    mounted() {
        this.fetchLogs();
    },
    methods: {
        fetchLogs() {
                axios.get('/api/logs/').then((res) => {
                this.logs= res.data.data;      
            });
        }
    }
}
```

```html
Filter: <input v-model="logFilterWord"/>

<log
    v-for="log in filteredlogs"
    :log="log"
    :key="log.id">
</log>
```

Copy the Code and try it out please, im at work so i cant debug it currently.

Comment: I get this errror: `The computed property "search_logs" is already defined in data.`
`found in ---> <LogsList> at resources\assets\js\components\logs\index.vue`

Comment: @Edo shouldnt be a problem of my code, i dont have such a property defined somewhere

Comment: Sorry this is the correct error: `[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined"`

Comment: I get an syntax error `return this.logs.filter(log => log.name === this.logFilterWord));`

Comment: @Edo oh i forgot to remove a bracket, just remove one of the right outer brackets :)

Comment: Nope i get now nothing, no errors but no results also.

Comment: @Edo yes type a name that exists in the search box then you will get results, i will write a good working example when im home ok?

Comment: Sounds good, but nope i won't get anything even when i search for an name.

Comment: @Edo ok i updated it again, i also wrote a example here http://jsfiddle.net/2gjdwrnt/ where you can orientate yourself on :)

Comment: I got it finally, thank you! You will get few votes and correct answer.

Comment: @Edo Glad to hear that it works now, im sorry that i needed so long but im not home so its hard for me to reproduce the code and test it before sending it to you

Comment: Basic i was tired with the same just used the same name for computed function property. HA but i got it with your help!

Comment: how can i search though all results not only the once that are paginated/showed ?

Comment: @Edo well it fetches the logs, it depends how many logs you fetch, like if you wanna search through other data then you would need the data somewhere first in a variable or something

Comment: I have all data in an array saved, Should i change the v-for property name ?

Comment: @Edo Please edit your post to the newest state because the state i see is that you fetch the data into an array?

Comment: I have the data here, `this.logs = res.data.data;` only logs, and the rest of the data `this.all_data = res.data;` since i need also to show total number of records etc.

Comment: @Edo give me an example dataset somewhere and tell me if it should be both in the same search, then i code you an example, but i make lunch now so will take a bit of time.

Comment: Okay, i have not all the data, since i paginate in the controller(php), how should be smarter to search for all records ? Because as it it now would only search for 10 records (i need to show only 10 per page). 

I can send all the data from the controller but then i would need another `axios.get` method right ? Then how can i separate the show and the search ?

Comment: Would be smart at all to read the data twice idk.. Any ideas @Badgy :) (Good Appetite for lunch break).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181278/discussion-between-badgy-and-edo).